# Proof is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

Consider a set of polynomials of degree 2 or lower with complex coefficients, $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{C})$. On this space we define the inner product
$$\langle p,q\rangle = p(0)\overline{q(0)} + \int_{0}^{1} p'(x)\overline{q'(x)}dx$$
we define the following operator $(S(p(x)) = p(-x)$, thus S mirrors the function in vertical axis. Is $S$ self-adjoint?

My intuition says no, but I cannot find a counter example, could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Why your intuition says no? Did you tried to find the adjoint of $S$?

Comment: It might help to write down the definition of self-adjoint.

Comment: Oh, you are right. So after trying, I got that $\langle S^*(p), p\rangle = \langle p, p(-x)\rangle$ and I got that $S^*(p) = p(-x)$ so it is a self-adjoint!